# Node.JS installing CLD

Tags: c++, node.js, compilation

I'm trying to install the [CLD package](https://github.com/dachev/node-cld) in my notebook, but keep receiving error in compilation.

Some basic info about my installation:

```
OS: Win 7 Professional (64bit) 
Visual Studio: 2012 
Command used: npm install cld --msvs_version=2012
Node.JS version: 5.4.0
Virtual Memory on C drive and E drive are both between 4GB to 8GB.
```

With reference to MSVS's support site on [error C1060](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz7kx3y2(v=vs.110).aspx), I have tried option 2 and 3 but no luck. Would anyone be able advise on this error? Detailed log is as below.

```
E:\node_modules\nan\nan.h(70): fatal error C1060: compiler is out of heap space (..\src\cld.cc) [E:\node_modules\cld\build\cld.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\node_modules\cld
gyp ERR! node -v v5.4.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN ENOENT ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\package.json'
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON !invalid#1 No description
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON !invalid#1 No repository field.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON !invalid#1 No README data
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON !invalid#1 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cld" "--msvs_version=2012"
npm ERR! node v5.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! cld@2.4.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cld@2.4.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the cld package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls cld
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to install [VS2013 Express Desktop version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=44914). Then re-install.

`npm install cld --msvs_version=2013`

reference: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/README.md#installation

Comment: Thanks man! You made my day! I'm just wondering why VS 2012 doesn't work but 2013 does. Is there any significant difference between them?