# NodeJS CLD package external dependency

Tags: node.js, compilation, compiler-errors, c++builder

I had [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34718832/node-js-installing-cld) installing [CLD package](https://github.com/dachev/node-cld) into one of my machine, so I tried to install it into another machine and the installation works perfectly.

In the good machine, I installed the CLD package and wrote a simple app.js around it.

```
var cld = require('cld');
console.log('cld loaded');
```

When running this in the good machine, I receive console output "cld loaded" as expected. I copied the exact same code including the node_modules folder into the other machine and run it, I receive errors in the console output:

```
E:\Test>node app.js
module.js:423
return process.dlopen(module, path._makeLong(filename));
             ^

Error: The specified procedure could not be found.
\\?\E:\Test\node_modules\cld\build\Release\cld.node
at Error (native)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:423:18)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Test\node_modules\cld\index.js:2:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
```

I can confirm the file "E:\Test\node_modules\cld\build\Release\cld.node" is existing. I'm not sure what's the missing procedure here. I suspect there could be some external dependency required for the package.

Could anyone advise what could be the external dependency missing in the first installation?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out it's a node.js version issue. I downgrade my nose.js to 0.10.28 and it works fine. I suppose it's some bug to be fixed by CLD.